# Can't see Facebook app after adding myself as test user

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-settings

I'm an admin for my Facebook and tried to add myself as a test user as well.  After confirming and inputting my password and completely shut me out of my app and I can't get back in.  Neither can he other admins.

How can we restore our app, it doesn't appear anything broke and the app still exists.  Just no one can get into it.

Comment: This sounds like an issue that you'll need to take up with Facebook. I'm not sure that the users of [so] will be able to assist you here as it is not really related to programming at all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is regarding Facebook customer support.